# Bug and the grass, when will it climb?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If grass is 3 cm long and bug climbs 2 cm/h and grass grows 1 cm/h after how many hours will it climb? My teacher said that it will climb after 1.5 hours, how?Bug will climb 2 cm, there will be 1 cm left and also 1 cm more because grass grows 1 cm/h so there will be 2 cm left for the bug to climb, it will climb 2 more and 1 will grow again, after that bug will finally climb up after 3 hours of climbing, what is wrong here?

Comment: grass grows from the bottom, maybe? So it lifts the bug with it.

Comment: Grass stretches as it grows?

Comment: Well yes i already said that (the sentence after my teachers' answer).

Comment: If the grass grows from the top, then you are correct and your teacher is wrong. If the grass grows from the bottom, then your teacher is correct and you are wrong. Are you sure this was asked in Math class and not in Biology class???

Comment: @barakmanos Looks as though you spoke truer than you knew - see Harald's comment below my answer! :)

Comment: Actually the bug is climbing down and not up (just remembered it),  grass is 3 cm long (bug is at the top) and when grass grows from the bottom won't it push the bug up (which will make it's climbing longer)?

Comment: @user3711671 Magical! :) Take your teacher the material that Harald references!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difficulty is that the bug climbs at 2cm/h *relative to the grass*. Now how exactly does the grass grow, does every little bit of it expand, or does it put on new height at the top, or at the bottom?

You are assuming it puts on new height at the top. In which case your answer is correct. Your teacher is assuming it puts on new height at the bottom, so after 1.5 hours it has reached the top of the original stalk, which has now been got new stalk length 1.5cm underneath it.

The interesting case is the middle case. Maybe you would like to tackle that?

Oh, what does grass really do? Well you cannot expect a mathematician to be interested in that, can you? :)

[Added later] Well. It seems that the original question maybe had the bug climbing down! So Harald's reference is good evidence that the teacher is wrong. Teachers after all are expected to be almost omniscient :)

Comment: [Here is a reference](http://www.answers.com/Q/How_does_grass_grow) claiming that it grows (almost) from the bottom.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen No good theorist believes an experimental result unless it has solid theoretical support! :) But interesting.

Comment: The explanation on the page I linked to is really more theoretical than empirically based. Anyhow, in science, theory and experiment should not be in competition, they should support each other.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I completely agree with you. But at nearly 11pm I was feeling tired and essaying humour. Without success, evidently :(

Comment: I was tired too. Still, I did find your comment funny, if not totally on target.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks. There is much I could say on the relationship between maths and the sciences, but this is not the place! I suspect we would largely agree.

Answer (score 0):

The height of the grass at time $t\geq0$ is given by
$$h(t)=3+t\ .$$
A grass molecule which is at height $y_0\in[0,3]$ at time $0$ moves proportionally  upwards according to $$y(t)={3+t\over 3} y_0\ .$$
It follows that the upwards speed of this molecule is given by
$$\dot y(t)={1\over3} y_0={y(t)\over 3+t}\ .$$
This means that when the bug is at height $b$ at time $t$ it gets a free ride upwards of speed ${b\over 3+t}$. The initial problem describing the movement of the bug is therefore given by
$$\dot b={b\over 3+t}+2\quad (t\geq0),\qquad b(0)=0\ .\tag{1}$$
The solution of $(1)$ is
$$b(t)=2(3+t)\log\left(1+{t\over3}\right)\ .$$
We now have to determine the $t$ for which $b(t)=3+t$. The solution is
$$t_*=3\bigl(\sqrt{e}-1\bigr)\doteq1.946\ .$$